# Why do I end up with two processes?

Tags: bash

I wrote a script that has been running as a daemon for quite some time now.
If I ever needed to debug it, I would stop the daemon version and rerun manually in current shell.  I have never logged anything out of this script, but as I am getting ready to deploy it on a remote server I figured I want to log any errors that the script would get into.  For that purpose I followed hints from several SO postings and am doing the following:

```
if ! tty > /dev/null; then
  exec > >(/bin/logger -p syslog.warning -t mytag -i) 2>&1
fi
```

This seems to log just fine, I am just surprised to see two instances of my script listed by `ps` when this feature is enabled.  Is there a way to avoid it?

I know I get another process for `logger` and I assume that it has to do with the `>(...)`, but still hope to avoid it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash spawns a subshell to execute the command(s) in `>( ... )`.  In this case, the only thing that subshell does is run `/bin/logger`, so it's rather pointless.  I think you can "fix" this with another exec command:

```
if ! tty > /dev/null; then
    exec > >(exec /bin/logger -p syslog.warning -t mytag -i) 2>&1
fi
```

This doesn't prevent the subshell from starting, but then instead of running `/bin/logger` as a subprocess (of the subshell), the subshell gets replaced with `/bin/logger`.  I haven't tested this with `logger`, but it worked fine in a quick test I did with `cat` and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Thanks - that new exec seem to do the trick ... I guess the second instance of my shell stuck around because it was the parent of logger

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PPID column. (parent process), I think you'll see that the 2 processes are connected to each other.

Generally commands surounded by '( )' pairs indicate 'running-as-a-subprocess', hence 2 listings in ps because there *are* 2 copies of the process.
(I'm not familiar with the bash syntax `exec > **${spaceChar}** >( .... ) 2>&1`, meaning the '>' seperated by a space from the 2nd '>'  )

**What is wrong with a crontab entry?**

Comment: Looking at the PPID is a good hint (give Gordon's working answer).  About crontab - isn't it more appropriate for short jobs?  Would you start httpd with a crontab entry?